# Why is a branch named HeaderTwo automatically created in VS Code by npx create-react-app

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch

[image: the branch name (HeaderTwo) automatically created for each folder]

Every time I `npx create-react-app appname` the `HeaderTwo` branch is automatically created.

I try `git branch -d HeaderTwo`, doesn't work.

The Chinese in the image is "Desktop".

Comment: I'd guess you have some global git config setting that as the default. What exactly do you mean that deleting it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are inside some other git repository folder that is already in HeaderTwo.
check the root folder(REACT PROJECT).

If you need to delete a local git branch first switch to one another branch and
try `git branch -D branchName`